# How do I get global teardown to work with Playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright, teardown

I've been trying to set up a global teardown for a Playwright, but I can't find any way to get it to run. I've tried following the examples in the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown), but it still doesn't work for some reason. I'm not running a setup, but I don't see how it would effect the running of teardown. In the config, I just use the `globalTeardown` option to point to the file that I want to run. Here is an example of what I have in the file I'm pointing to;

```js
async function globalTeardown(_config: FullConfig) {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = new CustomPage(await context.newPage());

    try{
        await context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });
        cleanUpFunc(page);

        await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
        context.tracing.stop({ 
            path: './test-results/teardown-trace.zip',
        });
        await browser.close();
        throw("Global setup error:\n" + error);
    }

}
```

Then in `cleanUpFunc`, it'd just be some functions that are on the `Page` object, or `CustomPage` object that I can't really come up with an example of.

I can't provide specific code, as I am under NDA, but I can try to provide an example, if needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one knows what code you run, but probably you don't await cleanUpFunc.

```
// global-teardown.ts

async function globalTeardown() {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  try {;
    await context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });
    await cleanUpFunc(page);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error in globalTeardown: ${e}`);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
}

export default globalTeardown;
```

and config

```
// playwright.config.ts

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  globalTeardown: "./global-teardown.ts",
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't notice that! I'm gonna try again and see if it works. It probably will, though. 